# Three.js : remove texture on top/bottom of CylinderGeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm using Three.js to make basic 3D cylinder rendering. I'm using TextureLoader to load texture async (based on UI interactions). 
All is ok, but I would like those textures not to be applied on the cylinder top / bottom.

How can I achieve that?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
function threeJsRenderer() {
  var width = 325;
  var height = 375;
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, -200, 1000);

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
  renderer.setSize(width,height);
  document.getElementById('projection').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // CylinderGeometry(radiusTop : Float, radiusBottom : Float, height : Float, radialSegments : Integer, heightSegments : Integer, openEnded : Boolean, thetaStart : Float, thetaLength : Float)
  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(135,128,110,64,1, false, 0, Math.PI-2);
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

  var cone = new THREE.Mesh();

  var pointLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF );
  pointLight.position.x = 10;
  pointLight.position.y = 50;
  pointLight.position.z = 130;
  scene.add(pointLight);

  camera.position.z = 40;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  cone.rotation.x = 0.01;
  cone.rotation.y = -10;

  jQuery(document).on('new3DConfigReady', function () {
    scene.remove(cone);
    var newGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(state.cylinderGeometry.radiusTop,state.cylinderGeometry.radiusBottom,state.cylinderGeometry.height,64,1, false, 0, Math.PI-2);;
    cone = new THREE.Mesh(newGeometry, material);
    cone.rotation.x = 0.01;
    cone.rotation.y = -0.55;  
    cone.position.y = state.cylinderGeometry.positionY;


    geometry.dispose();  
    if(state.textureUrl !== ''){
      scene.add(cone);
    }  

  });

  jQuery(document).on('newTextureReady', function () {
    loader.load( state.textureUrl, function (texture){
      material.map = texture;
      material.map.anisotropy = 256; 
      material.map.needsUpdate = true;
      material.needsUpdate = true;
      scene.add(cone);

    });
  });

  var render = function () {

    requestAnimationFrame(render);  
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  render();
}
```

Comment: Look into geometry groups. You will likely have two materials (one for the ends, and one for the texture) and three groups (one end, the sides, and the other end). When you create your mesh, you'll provide the materials as an array, and each group should reference a material index into that array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a materials array you can have different materials on the sides and ends of your cylinder.

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 10, 16, 1 );

var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture } ),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } )
];

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
```

three.js r.100

Comment: Same here, but well it works great. But still, I don't understand how materials[1] refers to the top (e.g., I guess) of the cylinder. I don't find any docs about materials array order.

Comment: @enguerranws This feature is currently not well-documented. three.js r.100